# Unable to delete user from Admin panel which was created using Django-Allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am new to Django and trying to add social login options to a project I am working on. I am currently using `Django-Allauth` for the same. Currently I have incorporated only Google login into my project. Everything works fine. I have created a custom user model for my project with email as the username. When a user tries to sign up using the Sign Up template I have provided, I can delete the user from the database without any problems. But if I try to delete any user from the admin panel who signed in using the Google option of django-allauth, I get `__str__ returned non-string (type CustomUser)` error. Only way for me to reset everything is to simply delete the model and redo everything. Below is how my model looks like. I am using Django 3.0 and the latest version of Django-Allauth. I am not sure how to solve this problem. Any help on this would be appreciated.

***models.py***

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, default='')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.first_name and self.last_name:
            return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        if self.first_name:
            return self.first_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        """
        Does the user have a specific permission?
        """
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        """
        Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?
        """
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users-profile', args=[str(self.id)])
```

***Settings.py***

```
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Default Apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',  # Added

    # User Apps
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',  # Added
)

# Required for Django-Allauth
SITE_ID = 1

# Required for Django-Allauth
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
```

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

**Below is the error traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/customuser/

Django Version: 3.0
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'contacts.apps.ContactsConfig',
 'API.apps.ApiConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'admin_honeypot',
 'rest_framework',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'users.middleware.OneSessionPerUserMiddleware')



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1704, in changelist_view
    response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1390, in response_action
    response = func(self, request, queryset)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\actions.py", line 28, in delete_selected
    deletable_objects, model_count, perms_needed, protected = modeladmin.get_deleted_objects(queryset, request)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1826, in get_deleted_objects
    return get_deleted_objects(objs, request, self.admin_site)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 151, in get_deleted_objects
    to_delete = collector.nested(format_callback)
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 211, in nested
    roots.extend(self._nested(root, seen, format_callback))
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 195, in _nested
    children.extend(self._nested(child, seen, format_callback))
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 197, in _nested
    ret = [format_callback(obj)]
  File "D:\Programs\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 126, in format_callback
    no_edit_link = '%s: %s' % (capfirst(opts.verbose_name), obj)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/users/customuser/
Exception Value: __str__ returned non-string (type CustomUser)
```

Comment: can you add error traceback?

Comment: try this way: def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)

Comment: @Nalin Dobhal, Updated the question with error traceback!

Comment: @bmons, let me try your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: @bmons, unfortunately, changing the return statement to `return str(self.email)` did not help. It still gives me the same error when I try to delete a user created from django-allauth!

Comment: change the return to self.first_name to see the error still there.

Comment: @Code_Sipra add the entire traceback instead of the image, this image is not very helpful.

Comment: @bmons, I get the same error as before even after making the change as you suggested. It looks like something is broken after including Django-Allauth because without it, everything works as intended.

Comment: have you added AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.yourCustomUser' in your settings?

Comment: @Nalin Dobhal, My apologies. Just updated the traceback. Hope that could point things in the right direction. Not very experienced when it comes to highlighting or explaining errors.

Comment: also add this line to your user model  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

Comment: @bmons, yes I have. This entire code is available in my github repository too although I haven't yet pushed any commits after trying to include social logins as I am getting these errors. Also, I added USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' and still, the error exists.

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractBaseUser` has a `__str__` method, which returns the field specified on `USERNAME_FIELD` in the model. You can check the source code on [Github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py).

So after you specify custom `USERNAME_FIELD`, you can remove your own `__str__` method:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, default='')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Also make sure that you [installed and configured the packaged properly](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: I have already included USERNAME_FIELD in the custom model as defined in the Django documentation. I just updated the models.py code in my question for more clarity. Let me try removing the `__str__` method from the code and see how everything runs.

Comment: I completely removed the `__str__` method from the CustomUser model. Deleted the existing database and completely redid all the migrations just to be sure I am not missing anything. But even then, I am unable to delete a user from Admin panel who had successfully signed using the Google sign in option from Django-Allauth. I even rechecked if I have configured django-allauth correctly. According to me, I did. Could there be some compatibility problems with Django 3.0?

Comment: have you figured out a way to do this?